# Closed form for infinite sum involving Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: generating-functions, chebyshev-polynomials

There exists a generating function for the Chebyshev polynomials in the following form:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{n}(x) \frac{t^n}{n} = \ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1 - 2tx + t^2 }}\right)$$

**Question:** can one find a similar closed form for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{2n}(x) \frac{t^n}{n}$ ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It suffices to observe that
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{n}(x) \frac{(\color{red}-t)^n}{n} = \ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1 \color{red}+ 2tx + t^2 }}\right)$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
\ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1 - 2tx + t^2 }}\right) + \ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1 + 2tx + t^2 }}\right) &= 2\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}, 2|n}T_{n}(x) \frac{t^n}{n} \\
&= 2\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}T_{2m}(x)\frac{t^{2m}}{2m}\\
&= \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}T_{2m}(x)\frac{(\color{red}{t^{2} })^m}{m}
\end{align}$$
$$\implies \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{2n}(x) \frac{t^n}{n}=\ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1 - 2\sqrt{t}x + t }}\right) + \ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1 + 2\sqrt{t}x + t }}\right) 
$$

Comment: Thank you ! Just a typo I guess, ie. the power 2 in the $t$ term should disappear: $$\implies \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{2n}(x) \frac{t^n}{n}=\ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1 - 2\sqrt{t}x + t }}\right) + \ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1 + 2\sqrt{t}x + t }}\right) $$

Comment: @edrezen Agreed, I corrected it.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record, here is a little modification to NN2's answer in order to avoid the inner square root for $t$:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{2n}(x) \frac{t^n}{n} =
- \frac{1}{2} \, \ln \bigg ( 1 + 2\,(1-2x^2)\,t + t^2 \bigg)  
$$

Answer (score 1):

Following NN2's idea, I figured out a generalization for the formula. If we note:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{n}(x) \frac{t^n}{n} = 
- \frac{1}{2} \, 
\ln \bigg( 1 + P_0(x)\,t + t^2  \bigg) \ \ \ \ with \ \ \ P_0(x)=-2x
$$
then we will have:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{2n}(x) \frac{t^n}{n} =
- \frac{1}{2} \, 
\ln \bigg( 1 + P_1(x)\,t + t^2  \bigg) 
$$
with
$$ P_1(x)=2-P_0^2(x)$$

More generally, we will have :
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{n\,2^k}(x) \frac{t^n}{n} = 
- \frac{1}{2} \, 
\ln \bigg( 1 + P_k(x)\,t + t^2  \bigg) \ \ \ \ with \ \ \ P_{k}(x) = 2 - P_{k-1}^2(x)
$$

The first $P_n$ polynomials are:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P_0(x) &= -2x       \\
P_1(x) &= -4x^2 + 2 \\
P_2(x) &= -16x^4 + 16x^2 - 2 \\
P_3(x) &= -256x^8 + 512x^6 - 320x^4 + 64x^2 - 2 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}